# Nothing is hidden when I run the hide() function

Tags: autodesk-forge

I'm running into this problem when I'm trying to run the fairly simple operation of hiding select nodes on a model in a displayed Revit file. I've got a custom button to trigger the function, and the model browser shows the nodes as hidden and getHiddenNodes() returns the nodes in question as hidden, but they're still showing on the visible model, see attached picture for example.

I'm also running invalidate(). Am I forgetting something?

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48HFg.png)

Comment: this.viewerApp.hide(ids);

this.viewerApp.impl.invalidate(true, true, true);

is the code I'm running.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, designs have duplicate, overlaying geometry, so that when you hide one, the other remains visible. When you hide a node, find its dbID (for example, using the `getHiddenNodes` method you mentioned), then *select* the node you can still see in the viewer, and check if it has the same dbID.

If the dbID is different, you might be dealing with this duplicate geometry issue as well, and may need to check the input design.

If the dbID is the same, in other words, if you you can still select an object with the same dbID that's returned by `getHiddenNodes`, we'd need to report a bug. In that case I'd ask you to share the design file with us (confidentially, only within Autodesk) via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`.